# three js change the position of shadow camera of directlight

Tags: three.js

I have a huge plane that I'm using as a ground, i have a directionalLight as the sun light.

the problem is, this directionalLight can't cast shadow over all the plane, so I've decided to make the shadow camera of the directionalLight to follow the main PerspectiveCamera.

So, this my code:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
lightCameraConstant = 40;
dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
dirLight.color.setHSL( 0.1, 0.5, 1 );
dirLight.position.set( 1500, 2000, 1500 );
dirLight.castShadow = true;

dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 4096;
dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 4096;

dirLight.shadow.camera.left = -lightCameraConstant;
dirLight.shadow.camera.right = lightCameraConstant;
dirLight.shadow.camera.top = lightCameraConstant;
dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -lightCameraConstant;
dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 3000;
dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.01;
dirLight.shadow.bias = -0.0001;
scene.add( dirLight );
var helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( dirLight.shadow.camera );
    scene.add( helper );
```

then in the animation function i use the following:

```
dirLight.shadow.camera.position.x = camera.position.x;
helper.update();
```

but this is not working, the shadow camera isn't changing its position at all.

1- how to change shadow camera position without changing the directionalLight position ?

2- is there any way to cover casting shadow over a big area without using insane resources ?

Comment: As Marquizzo says below, (2) is a broad question and better suited to http://discourse.threejs.org/. If it could be concisely and robustly solved in a Stack Overflow answer, that solution would be built into three.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't change the position of shadow camera, but I found a work around.

The workaround was, to change the whole directLight position and the target position with the main camera in a way that the angel between the target position and the directLight stay the same.

I used this could:

```
dirLight.position.x = camera.position.x - cameraStartPosition.x + 20 ;
dirLight.position.z = camera.position.z - cameraStartPosition.z + 20;
dirLight.target.position.set(( camera.position.x - cameraStartPosition.x),0,(camera.position.z - cameraStartPosition.z));
```

`cameraStartPosition` is the start position of the camera, because my camera isn't starting at 0,0,0. and the rest of the fixed numbers are an offset that I want to keep between the main camera and the shadow camera.

Hope this could help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add **light target** to scene including **light**.

```
scene.add(light.target);
```

then move light target and light

```
light.position.set(robot.position.x,light.position.y,robot.position.z);
light.target.position.set(robot.position.x,light.target.position.y,robot.position.z);
```